# An example that $G/N$ cyclic does not imply $G$ cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $G$ a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. A known fact is that if $G$ is cyclic, then the quotient group $G/N$ is cyclic too. Other fact is that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, where $Z(G)$ denoted the center of $G$, then $Z(G) = G$. What would be an example of that $G/N$ is cyclic, but $G$ is not cyclic?

Comment: $N=G=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ :)

Comment: Any noncyclic group $G$ and $N=G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G=S_3$ and $N=A_3$.

Then $G$ is not cyclic (not even Abelian), but $G/N$ has order $2$ and is cyclic.

Comment: In fact, any non-cyclic group with a subgroup of index $2$ (such as the one in the comment by  [TokenToucan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/208649/tokentoucan)) would work

Comment: NB, here even $N$ is cyclic as well. This suggests the generalization: any solvable group